# Collection of NSFetchRequests in Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift3

I have an object that uses a dictionary of key paths to fetch requests. Each fetch request represents a different entity. This is all fine and working under Swift 2.3 and below. However, when I try to convert my project to Swift 3, I run into issues with the new generics for fetch requests. Fetch requests tend to have the type that they return associated with them, but my dictionary needs to have fetch requests that return all kinds of types. When I try to create a dictionary of type `[String:NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>]` or `[String:NSFetchRequest< NSFetchRequestResult >]` with fetch requests that are specifically of type `NSFetchRequest<Message>`. (`Message` being an NSManagedObject subclass) I get a compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest< Message >' to expected
>   dictionary

value type 'NSFetchRequest'

*How can I downcast one fetch request to a more general fetch request type?*

Comment: Declare the dictionary entry to be `AnyObject`, or else use `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Could you please share the ```Swift2``` code here, so that we can try to convert it to ```Swift3```

Comment: Using a more general dictionary would work ([String: NSPersistentStoreRequest] would work too) but would then require a cast when I read from the dictionary. But that made me think, could you cast one type of NSFetchRequest to another? You can! `fetchRequestA as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>` works. It's fairly clunky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can cast from one fetch request type to another. It's kind of clunky though. I can't imagine there being a situation where the cast would fail. In ObjC you wouldn't even need the cast.

```
class A: NSManagedObject {}
class B: NSManagedObject {}

let fetchRequestA = NSFetchRequest<A>()
let fetchRequestB = NSFetchRequest<B>()

let fetchRequests: [String:NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>] = [
    "a" : fetchRequestA as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>,
    "b" : fetchRequestB as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>,
]
```